# Read/write permissions for /var/www?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, user-management, groups, user-permissions

I've got a Debian 8 server running where `/var/www` is owned by `www-data` and has the permissions `drwxr-xr-x` for both, files and subdirectories.

Since I need to upload files via SFTP (public/private key authentication; password and non-encrypted FTP is blocked) I thought it should be no problem to add my user account to the group `www-data`. Thus, I exectued:

```
sudo usermod --append --groups www-data my-user
```

I already logged out of the current SSH session in order to trigger a reload of the permissions. `id my-user` now shows:

```
uid=1000(my-user) gid=1000(my-user) groups=1000(my-user),33(www-data)
```

However, I am still unable to write data via SFTP in `/var/www`. Even a simple `touch test.txt` directly via SSH fails with `Permission denied`.

I thought `rwx` is `read`, `write` and `execute`. Obviously my understanding of the directory/file permissions is incomplete. Can someone help?

Comment: The first `rwx` on your current permissions, are the users own permissions, not the group. The group permissions are `r-x` (the next three characters). Your confusion lies in that the user and group have the same name. The user `www-data` and the group `www-data` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state the permissions for /var/www are `drwxr-xr-x` which is `rwx` for owner only.  Group has `r-x` which means even though you added yourself to the `www-data` group, the directory does not allow the group write permission to /var/www.

`chmod g+w /var/www` to allow your account to be able to add files to /var/www.

If there are any subdirectories beneath /var/www, you will want to do the same `chmod` command if you need to be able to write to those directories ever.

Also consider setting the group sticky bit so all files created in /var/www will have `www-data` as the group.

`chmod g+s /var/www`

Again, for any subdirectories underneath /var/www, you will want to add this as well.

Comment: Ok. So is it safe to do `chmod -R g+s+w /var/www` to do it all in once?

Comment: Yes, but correct syntax is `chmod -R g+sw /var/www`

Comment: Actually, the sticky bit really only applies to directories.  Maybe `find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+sw {} \;`  That will find the directories and change the permissions.

Comment: One more quick question: it is enough that any created file/directory in /var/www always has `www-data` as the group?! So, it is irrelevant that the user will be `my-user` when I create files there?!

Comment: Any files in /var/www need to be _readable_ by either the owner or group owner of your web server which seems to be `www-data` in your case.  So yes, it will be irrelevant that `my-user` owns files you put in /var/www as long as the group is `www-data` or the files permissions include `o+r`.

Answer (score 1):

You said permissions is drwxr-xr-x, so 755, and you added yourself to www-data group, so you need, 775, that is drwxrwxr-x.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just read this http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm to understand what these numbers are. Really nice shortcut for setting permissions :)